# RTCPeerConnection Remains in "Connecting" State on Raspberry Pi with socket.io Signaling

Tags: socket.io, raspberry-pi, webrtc, video-streaming, aiortc

I've been trying to implement a video streaming solution using aiortc in Python, with signaling over socket.io. The main goal is to capture video from a webcam on a Raspberry Pi and stream it to a remote endpoint. Everything seems to work fine when I run my code on Windows; the RTCPeerConnection state transitions to "connected". However, on Raspberry Pi, the state remains stuck at "connecting". Camera access is not an issue as I can confirm it's operational.

I've attached the relevant code below:

```
# Socket.io client is initialized.
sio = socketio.AsyncClient()

@sio.event
async def connect():
    print("Connected to server")

@sio.event
async def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected from server")
    if camera_stream and camera_stream.container:
            camera_stream.container.close()
            print("closed the camera_stream")

# Upon receiving joinRequest, send the offer using makeCall event.
@sio.on("joinRequest")
async def async_on_join_request(data):
    print("joinRequest")
    print(offer)
    offer_data = {
        "type": offer.type,
        "sdp" : offer.sdp
    }
    await sio.emit("makeCall", {"to": data["socket"], "offer": offer_data})
    
# Upon receiving callAnswered, set the remote description.
@sio.on("callAnswered")
async def async_on_call_answered(message):
    print("callAnswered")
    print(message)
    if "answer" in message and "type" in message["answer"] and "sdp" in message["answer"]:
        if peer_connection.signalingState == "have-local-offer":
            remote_desc = RTCSessionDescription(type=message["answer"]["type"], sdp=message["answer"]["sdp"])
            await peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(remote_desc)
        else:
            print("Ignoring answer because signaling state is not 'have-local-offer'. Current state:", peer_connection.signalingState)
    else:
        print("Received message does not have the expected structure.")
    
def parse_ice_candidate(data: dict) -> dict:
    sdp = data['iceCandidate']['candidate']
    parts = sdp.split(' ')

    return {
        "component": int(parts[1]),  # RTP
        "foundation": parts[0].split(":")[1],
        "ip": parts[4],
        "port": int(parts[5]),
        "priority": int(parts[3]),
        "protocol": parts[2],
        "type": parts[7]
    }

@sio.on("iceCandidate")
async def async_on_ice_candidate(data):
    parsed = parse_ice_candidate(data)
    print("#################### iceCandidate data: ")
    print(data)
    candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
        component=parsed["component"],
        foundation=parsed["foundation"],
        ip=parsed["ip"],
        port=parsed["port"],
        priority=parsed["priority"],
        protocol=parsed["protocol"],
        type=parsed["type"],
        sdpMid=data['iceCandidate']["sdpMid"],
        sdpMLineIndex=data['iceCandidate']["sdpMLineIndex"]
    )
    print("==================== iceCandidate parsed data: ")
    print(candidate)
    await peer_connection.addIceCandidate(candidate)

async def initialize_video_stream():
    try:
        global camera_stream
        camera_stream = VideoStreamTrack()
        # A video track from the camera is added to the peer connection.   
        peer_connection.addTrack(camera_stream)

        global offer
        offer = await peer_connection.createOffer()
        await peer_connection.setLocalDescription(offer)

        # Emit the videoServer event.
        await sio.emit("videoServer")
        print("Initialize video stream")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error initializing video stream: {e}")
```

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.